# Probability problem with random vectors

Tags: probability, random-variables

**Problem**

Suppose that $10$% of the american population smokes dark cigarettes, $35$% smokes white cigarettes, $3$% smokes pipe and the rest of the population doesn't smoke. A group of $35$ persons was surveyed and with the obtained results, we define the random variables:
$$Y_1=\{\text{number of people who smoke dark cigarettes}\}$$$$Y_2=\{\text{number of people who smoke light cigarettes}\}$$$$Y_3=\{\text{number of persons who smoke pipe}\}$$$$Y_4=\{\text{number of non smokers}\}$$

1) Find the probability mass of $(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4)$ and the probability mass of $(Y_1,Y_2+Y_3,Y_4)$.

2) Find the probability mass of $Y_2+Y_3$.

This is what I could do:

1) I'll abbreviate $p_{Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4}(i,j,k,l)=p(i,j,k,l)$$$p(i,j,k,l)=\begin{cases} 0 & \mbox{if } i+j+k+l \neq 35 \\ {35 \choose i}{35-i \choose j}{35-i-j \choose k}{35-i-j-k \choose l}(\frac{1}{10})^i(\frac{7}{20})^j(\frac{3}{100})^k(\frac{13}{25})^l & \mbox{if } i+j+k+l=35 \end{cases}$$

I would like to know if what I've done is correct and I would appreciate help to calculate the other probability masses. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The mess of binomial coefficients would look better as a single multinomial coefficient, or in terms of factorials, to look more symmetric.  The $i,j,k,l$ probably should be in the order that $Y_1$ to $Y_4$ are listed.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, I've corrected the order of the variables.

Comment: For $(Y_1,Y_2+Y_3,Y_4)$ just lump the two types of cigarettes together, probability $45/100$, so now we only have three indices instead of four. 2) is even simpler, binomial random variable $p=45/100$.

Comment: Note that the product of the binomial coefficients in front is $\frac{35!}{i!j!k!l!}$, aka the multinomial coefficient $\binom{35}{i,j,k,l}$.

Comment: When you changed the order of the $Y_i$, you changed the meaning of $Y_2+Y_3$. If the original problem had $Y_1$ the non-smokers, then the $i$ should have been associated with $Y_1$, so first term $(13/25)^i$.

Answer (score 0):

a) Using the multinomial coefficient, we have
$$P(Y_1 = i, Y_2 = j, Y_3 = k, Y_4 = l) = \binom{35}{i,j,k,l}\left(\frac{10}{100}\right)^i\left(\frac{35}{100}\right)^j\left(\frac{3}{100}\right)^k\left(\frac{52}{100}\right)^l$$

b) Instead of considering four categories, we know consider three categories where categories two and three have been collapsed together. So you could say
\begin{align*}
X_1 &= \{\text{Number of people who smoke dark cigarettes}\}\\
X_2 &=\{\text{Number of people who light cigarettes or pipes}\}\\
X_3&=\{\text{Number of nonsmokers}\}
\end{align*}
Since you seemed to understand part a), then this should not very different.

c) Consider instead a fair six-sided die, and we wish to count the number of twos and threes in 35 rolls. Then it should be familiar that this follows a binomial distribution with $n = 35$, $p = 2/6$. Similarly, part c) also follows a binomial distribution with $n = 35,  p = 38/100$.